# How to place a checkbox next to a link_to tag in ERB file and when we check a box we should get the values of link_to tag of ERB?

Tags: jquery, erb

The front end looks like this if i select the checkbox and click on ClickMe button it should give only href of  of only checked ones

[image]

```
<td class='actions actions-1 my-files' data-hook="admin_orders_index_row_actions">
          <% doc = Spree::BookkeepingDocument.where(printable: shipment.order).last %>
          <% if doc %>
            <%= link_to_with_icon "file", "", admin_bookkeeping_document_path(doc, format: :pdf), title: "Download Invoice" %>
          <input type="checkbox" name="files" class="check"/>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<%= admin_bookkeeping_document_path(doc, format: :pdf)%>" name="my-files" style="margin-left: 30%;">
</span>
```

Add this snippet and after `link_to` tag and in check box attribute value give value of the `link_to` tag value.